# Use of a bitwise AND operator in filter

Tags: scala

Assuming I have a simple list of numbers, something like:

```
val numbers = List.range(1,10)
```

And I want to filter it, using & operator - the shortest solution that seems to be working is:

```
numbers.filter( x => ( x & 1 ) == 0 )
```

However I'm not sure why do I need () here, or x, but it seems to give me a following error otherwise (which seems that & is an issue, but I'm not sure how to look it up in docs):

```
//
// overloaded method value & with alternatives:
//     (x: Long)Long <and>
//     (x: Int)Int <and>
//     (x: Char)Int <and>
//     (x: Short)Int <and>
//     (x: Byte)Int
// cannot be applied to (Boolean)
// numbers.filter( _ & 1 == 0 ) 
//
numbers.filter( _ & 1 == 0 )
```

Also another confusing part, is that % operator works just fine.

```
// --- all good
numbers.filter( _ % 2 == 0 ) 

// --- error
//
// type mismatch;
//     found   : Int
//     required: Boolean
// numbers.filter( _ & 1 ) 
// 
numbers.filter( _ & 1 )
```

So why would "x % 2 == 0" work, and "x & 1 == 0" fail, because they produce similar results (I think). If I understand an error properly - the result of "x & 1" is an integer. And I assume it's something to do with & operator, but can't figure out where would I look it up.

Scala: 2.10

Thanks in advance for your help and any suggestions.

Comment: Because of operator precedence; `==` has higher precendence than `&`, so that `x & 1 == 0` means `x & (1 == 0)` and not `(x & 1) == 0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operators `%` and `&` have different priorities. So `_ & 1 == 0` tries to compare one to zero and then perform `&` on boolean result.

See [Scala Reference - 6.12.3 Infix Operations](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#infix-operations):

increasing order of precedence:

> ```
> (all letters)
> |
> ^
> &
> = !
> < >
> :
> + -
> * / %
> (all other special characters)
> ```